# couchdb complex map reduce over multiple documents give back single json object

Tags: dictionary, view, couchdb, scale, reduce

How to create a complex map reduce function in couchdb to span a view over multiple documents with same attribute names to give back a single json object?

What is the most efficient way to manage this?

Is a nested set/source algorithm suitable for couchdb (changes are very write intensive)?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to do?

Comment: in couchdb i have a lot of documents of the same type with same attributes. i want to aggregate all documents to a single json array object to parse it after http request response.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole documents you shouldn't use reduce. Just do a proper map function for the "type" attribute you talked about earlier and query the view with include_docs=true.

Comment: Could you describe the include_docs=true property on a example?

Comment: when you get back the view query it'll have another property next to "value" which is "doc" and that will be the whole document that was used to emit that key/value pair.

Comment: it's a querystring paramater BTW :)